# On Jenkins, is there a way to allow Build Logs to be viewed anonymously?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to expose the Build Logs (or Build output) from a job  anonymously if the URL is known?

I understand that there is the anonymous credentials on the Settings, however I'm not sure what option would only expose the build logs.[image]

I believe that I have seen it before where the log screen is a black screen that can be accessed anonymously, but I'm not sure what this is, or whether this was a Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, by default, Jenkins on install allows anonymous access. In fact all users can do anything, which is bad. You should lock down access using the [Role Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy) plugin and maybe also using the [Active Directory](https://plugins.jenkins.io/active-directory) plugin although using Jenkins own users is ok to start with.

I would encourage you to turn Security on and only give users the access they REALLY need via roles to perform their roles.  Often many roles on a development and test team ONLY need read access to Jenkins so they can see why their builds failed.  To avoid "bus-factor" concerns only one or maybe two other people need admin access.

If you REALLY need anonymous access to the console (I don't recommend it), Job -> Read is probably the most targeted permission to give access to see the job "console" log.

If the login screen is displayed you must of enabled security.  In which case you have to have a role other than Admin that has the Overall Read permission.

Comment: Thanks! I found just enabling Anonymous Job - > Read did not enable access to the job "console" log.  Instead the login screen was displayed.